# Why aren't all trade routes active?

Tags: endless-space

I have up to 0/3 trade routes in a system. If the maximum is 3 why there's none? How do I increase the number of working trade routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you'll need to befriend another (or additional) empires. For each peaceful system explored, you'll gain a trade route (up to the maximum supported by *your* home system). I would also suggest reading the overview [here](http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_Routes).